# Can one obtain a visa for Mauritania while in Australia?

Tags: visas, africa

I am in Australia. It seems from the  [Department of Foreign Affairs and Trade](http://protocol.dfat.gov.au/Mission/view.rails?id=127) there is no visa issuing facility here for Mauritania (looks like the nearest is in Tokyo).

Is there a way to get a tourist or transit visa while in Australia?

### Update

The reason I am asking this is because I do not fly in but will be coming overland from Senegal. According to [Mauritania Visa in Senegal](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/africa/mauritania/mauritania-visa-in-senegal) it could take a week in Senegal to obtain a visa. Hence would like to find a way to do so in advance.

Comment: Even without knowing your nationality, Timatic is showing that you can get a visa on arrival at Nouakchott Airport. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Mauritania) has the same.

Comment: In [Lonely Planet threads](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/africa/mauritania/visa-0d1b2db3-dc6b-407e-b44d-56c86f0289fa) of four years, some were able to get a visa at its embassy in Rabat, Morocco.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=MR&SECTION=VI&SUBSECTION=is&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), the database used by airlines:

> Nationals of any country can obtain a visa on arrival at Nouakchott (NKC).

In addition, various forums, such as [this](http://www.horizonsunlimited.com/hubb/morocco/mauritania-visa-at-border-81300), have anecdotal reports of it being possible to obtain a visa on arrival at land crossings too.

There is no Mauritanian embassy in Australia; as such, unless Tokyo accepts applications by regular mail, there is no option for getting it in advance while in Australia.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however unfortunately I do not fly in to NKC, hence look for a way to get in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Understood there would be no option. Will look into the option to get at crossing points or in countries where embassy resides.